# Objective C: Google analytics send event with custom dimension

Tags: ios, objective-c

Want to send a custom dimension in an event, but I do not see the dimension arrive in the dashboard of **Google Analytics**.

Where is my mistake?

```
+ (void)setEvent:(NSString *)category action:(NSString *)action label:(NSString *)label value:(NSString *)value {
    id <GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:value];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:category
                                                          action:action
                                                              label:label
                                                           value:nil] build]];

}
```

**Edit**

I just did a test, I put a string hardcoded instead of value and it worked. Why the value that passes in parameter isn't work? But I get the value because I printed it

Comment: you are doing everything ok, are you sure there is no events with dimensions?

Comment: I just did a test I put a string hardcoded instead of value and it worked. Why the value that passes in parameter it does not work? But I get the value because I it printed it